# deploying addon in atlassian marketplace

Tags: json, jira-plugin, ngrok

I have created an add-on in jira, in developement mode I uploaded them using localhost link from ngrok (https:// 32570d96.ngrok.io). Referring that URL in links and baseURL(add-on descriptor) as above in atlassian-connect.json.

Now, I have to release the add-on in atlassian marketplace. How can I release the add-on in marketplace(cloud based add-on)?

I have referred this link, for creating fields in addon descriptor: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/modules/#properties

For, uploding the add-on in atlassian marketplace, I followed these steps, as given here:
https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/developing/cloud-installation.html

**While uploading add-on, it ask for URL of addon descriptor. How to create addon descriptor URL by uploading the atlassian-connect.json in cloud instead of using ngrok(https:// 32570d96.ngrok.io/atlassian-connect.json)**

Currently, I use the format of add-on descriptor fields in atlassian-connect.json file, as shown below:

```
"baseUrl": "https://253e4f95.ngrok.io",
"links": {
    "self": "https://253e4f95.ngrok.io/atlassian-connect.json", 
    "homepage": "https://253e4f95.ngrok.io/atlassian-connect.json"
},
```

Comment: You need to host the add-on via your own server or app engine. The atlassian-connect-express readme includes instructions for deploying on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

> While uploading add-on, it ask for URL of addon descriptor. How to create addon descriptor URL by uploading the atlassian-connect.json in cloud instead of using ngrok(https:// 32570d96.ngrok.io/atlassian-connect.json)

ngrok is something that you use for local development and testing(https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/getting-started/). Obviously you cannot use same links to upload your descriptor in production ( cloud marketplace). You need to put is over some hosting site where your addon descriptor is reachable from a https url and also the certificates are not self signed.

You can use service like heroku to deploy your app/atlassian-connect.json file. You should be able to find able documentation on Heroku web app deployment online.

Being a AWS certified solutions architect I would recommend adding atlassian-connect.json to an S3 bucket and making this object publicly accessible and use the https url of this object to give to market place. Things would be must complicated when you start with actual app deployment in which case you will have to use load balancers and EC2 instances to deploy your server logic.